# Chrome doesn't play the sources which only support `http` protocol

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium, html5-audio

I have some audio sources that only support `http` protocol but I have problem with google chrome about playing them.

There is an example of my source that doesn't play in Chrome but plays in the Firefox.

What is the best solution in this situation?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls autoplay preload="none">
<source type="audio/mpeg" id="player" src="http://dl.tabamusic.com/Music/1400/01/Mohammadreza Ghaffari - Ashkam Aberoome (128).mp3">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get that you know you have a problem with Chrome?

Comment: @phuzi Chrome will change the request to `https` and raise an error regarding to access the url